# Dealer's directional open interest

Tags: options, gamma, open-interest

This question is related to the previous question I asked [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/76225/47318). In one of the answers, the article from Squeezemetrics that discusses the effect of GEX on the spot price of an asset was pointed out. GEX is an interesting concept. If indeed we can successfully calculate GEX, then negative GEX means there is an accelerating effect of options OI on the spot price in the direction of its movement. If GEX is positive, then it tends to pull the spot price towards that strike price as if it has a compressing effect. Here's the catch. The article requires something called 'dealer's directional open interest' (DDOI) whose computation is given in the last page of the document [here](https://squeezemetrics.com/monitor/static/guide.pdf). I find that explanation very vague. Hence I thought of asking folks on this forum about how exactly can we find DDOI if at all possible. The questions are in two parts.

1. Why does DDOI even differ from OI? If someone is long, someone else is short right? So why bother finding the OI of those people who are hedging their positions? Why would someone who is long an option hedge his/her position? Who in their right mind would short an option without hedging it? And how long can they hold such a position without going bankrupt?
   Long story short, I would think that anyone short an option should be hedging his position, and anyone going long an option does not hedge. Why then is DDOI even necessary to be defined?
2. Assuming that there are some crazy traders who sell options without hedging their position with the underlying, or that there are people who long an option and hedge it for reasons they know best, it makes sense to define DDOI. But then the article does not clearly explain the steps in the calculation of DDOI. Let me concretely define the  case and I will keep it generic so that you can answer it in some form of an algorithm based on the values of the variables.
   Suppose some stock or index has an option with OI of $oi_0$ and DDOI of $ddoi_0$ at the beginning of the candle (or before the tick update ... whatever the case maybe). Let it be $oi_1$ at the end of the candle. Let there be $b$ buy trades and $s$ sell trades in that candle for that option. How then do I find the DDOI, $ddoi_1$, at the end of that candle for that option?